# how to do ? get query object with one model and add where or join condition another model or controller using codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter-3

I have to call a user model and get object only and then add the conditions.
How can I do this?

```
function manager(){        
    $email = 'xxxx@gmail.com';
    $result = $this->user_model->getUserinformationData( );
    $result1= $result->where('user.email',$email);
    echo '<pre>';print_r($result1);exit;
}

function getUserinformationData(){
    $querysucess = $this->db->select('*')->get('user');
    return $querysucess;
}
```

Only get query object from model and add where or join condition another model or controller  how can I do that one.

Comment: you are trying to add the resulted query, not concatenate the query. If you are need to add query just create manual query, Since `$querysucess =   $this -> db -> select('*')-> get('user');  ` this will execute the query.

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass variable from controller to model as function parameter:

```
//controller method
public function manager()
{
    $email = 'xxxx@gmail.com';
    $result = $this->user_model->getUserinformationData($email);//pass to the model
    echo '<pre>', var_dump($result);
    exit;
}

//model method
function getUserinformationData($email)//$email is passed from controller
{
    $query = $this->db->get_where('user', ['email' => $email]);//second parameter of get_where() method as array of where conditions
    return $query;
}
```

You have that in [docs](https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/query_builder.html).